# Is there a Ramanujan's sum function with real argument?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In number theory, the Ramanujan sum function is defined as below: $$c_q(n)=\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le q\\ \gcd(k,q)=1}}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k n}{q}\right)$$ where $q,n$ are integers. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum) Wikipedia article shows a list of amazing properties of this arithmetic function. I was just wondering,

> Is there a generalization for this sum for real $n$? That is, if I define a function as $$c_q(r)=\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le q\\ \gcd(k,q)=1}}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k r}{q}\right)$$ where $r$ is a real number, is there any mention in the literature of such a function and some of its properties?

I searched a while but could not find any mention of such a function, and I am also not sure how to find properties of this function (that is properties equivalent to the case when $n$ is an integer) when $n$ is real (I pretty much could derive most of the properties when $n$ is an integer). For a specific example, when, $n$ is a positive integer, the Wikipedia article shows that there is an explicit formula for $c_q(n)$, found by Holder, $$c_{q}(n)=\mu\left(\frac{q}{\gcd(q,n)}\right)\frac{\phi(q)}{\phi\left(\frac{q}{\gcd(q,n)}\right)}$$ Is there such a formula available for the function when $n$ is real? Any help with references, or some ideas will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe this function has been studied when $n$ is a noninteger. This is because it is studied for its arithmetic properties; in particular, it is studied as an arithmetic function, which by definition means it is only defined for positive integers. For arbitrary $n$, it is of course still a well-defined function, but it no longer seems to have any practical uses.

Comment: In particular, the identity for $c_q(n)$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\phi$ is discussing the multiplicative properties of $c_q(n)$, and as soon as $n$ is no longer a positive integer, this ceases to make any sense. How do you define $\gcd(q,n)$ or $\phi(n)$ when $n$ isn't an integer? (And, more importantly, why would it be interesting or useful?)

Comment: @PeterHumphries $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(a) k^{-s}$ has some $1/\zeta(s)$ in it for every integer $a$, so it has good chances to be $1/\zeta(s)$-ish also for rational and real $a$, in that case it deserves to be mentioned

Comment: @PeterHumphries, I am not saying that I have to get formulas involving $\gcd(n,q)$, when $n$ is real, that would be stupid. But I think there got to be something close to that, for example when $n$ has a very small fractional part, then the value of this function must be close to the one evaluated at that integer value, get my drift?

Comment: @user1952009 thanks for the intuition. Yes, I am exactly after that kind of behavior of this function.

Comment: $$c_q(a) = \sum_{k = 0, gcd(q,k) = 1}^{q-1} e^{2i \pi ak/q}, \qquad \eta_q(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} e^{2i \pi ak/q} = \frac{1-e^{2i \pi a}}{1-e^{2i \pi a/q}}$$
Then
$\eta_q(a) = \sum_{d|q} c_{d}(a) \quad \implies \quad c_q(a) = \sum_{d | q} \eta_d(a) = \sum_{d | q}  \frac{1-e^{2i \pi a}}{1-e^{2i \pi a/d}}$
So that
$$G(a,s) = \sum_{q=1}^\infty c_q(a) q^{-s} = \sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{1-e^{2i \pi a}}{1-e^{2i \pi a/q}} q^{-s} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$
For $Im(a)>0$ expanding more you get
$G(a,s)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}(1-e^{2i \pi a})\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2i\pi am)^k}{k!} \zeta(s+k)$

Comment: Nice idea @user1952009!